# What could cause this ArgumentException from Directory.GetFiles?

Tags: c#, .net

The following snippet of code has been working fine for weeks but today I got this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
    at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
    at System.IO.Path.InternalCombine(String path1, String path2)
    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.GetFullSearchString(String fullPath, String searchPattern)
    at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler)
    at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
    at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(String searchPattern)
    at MyCompany.GetSendDefinition(String deviceId)
    ...
```

Here is the code

```
public SendDefinition GetSendDefinition(string deviceId)
{
    Logger.Debug("Definition for '{0}'" deviceId);

    string storePath = Path.Combine(_serviceFolder, TcpFolder);
    var info = new DirectoryInfo(storePath);
    if (!info.Exists)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var files = info.GetFiles(deviceId + "_????.txt");
    int numberOfMessage = files.Length;

    var file = files.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();
    if (file == null)
    {
        return new SendDefinition
                   {
                       Message = string.Empty,
                       NumberOfMessages = 0
                   };
    }

    string response;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
    {
        response = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\r\n", "");
    }

    string[] data = file.Name.Split('.');
    var name = data[0].Split('_');
    if (name.Length > 3)
    {
        var count = Convert.ToInt16(name[3],
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (count < 5)
        {
            count++;
            string newFileName = Path
                .Combine(storePath,
                         data[0].Substring(0, data[0].Length - 1)
                         + count + ".txt");
            file.CopyTo(newFileName, true);
        }
        file.Delete();
    }
    else
    {        
        string newFileName = Path.Combine(storePath,
                                          data[0] + "_0.txt");
        file.CopyTo(newFileName, true);
        file.Delete();
    }

    return new SendDefinition
                   {
                       Message = response,
                       NumberOfMessages = numberOfMessage
                   };

}
```

I thought, OK, the deviceId bit must be junk but looking in the log output I got:

```
Definition for '3912'
```

I think that the line of code that would be throwing that exception is the following but I do not have PDBs so I am not 100% sure hence posting the entire function.

```
var files = info.GetFiles(deviceId + "_????.txt");
```

I checked the [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) MSDN page to see what invalid characters are and I think that passing `"3912_????.txt"` into that function should be fine.

I figure the directory must be fine or that whole `.Exists` thing would have fallen over.

So do any of the great StackOverfloweions know what could possibly have made this happen (I just restarted my application and have not seen it happen again yet...)?

**Update**

Doing a dir in that directory I have the following:

```
14.03.2012  16:03    <DIR>          .
14.03.2012  16:03    <DIR>          ..
09.03.2012  13:51               101 3055_P_275112090312.txt
25.01.2012  10:52                99 3055_X_325209250112.txt
10.02.2012  08:38                74 3055_Z_373807100212.txt
           3 Datei(en)            274 Bytes
           2 Verzeichnis(se), 33.613.897.728 Bytes frei
```

Comment: The error message indicates it's failing on the info.GetFiles call.  That strongly suggests that the search path/pattern provided contains an invalid character.  Any possibility your device ID can be something other than what you've provided for examples?

Comment: I am using log4net (via the Castle Windsor logging facility) and whenever I have a replacement variable I wrap it in quotes like so '{0}' - my reasoning for doing this is because I thought that even if it is a weird character I would see it in my log.  I just checked and \0 logs as a space (e.g. '3913 ').

Comment: @user1039947 - logging of unprintable characters like \u0001 will depend on the encoding being used, so I would try logging the hex values of each character in `deviceId`.

Comment: OK, cool, thanks Joe - I will put your suggested code in and start it running again and see what happens - will update this if I get any more info tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is that `deviceId` contains an invalid character.

For example, a trailing null character ("\0") would give this result, and would probably not show up in your log.

You could check for this by tracing the values of each character in your deviceId string - e.g.:

```
Console.WriteLine("Device Id {0} ({1})", 
    deviceId,
    String.Join("-", deviceId.Select(x => ((int)x).ToString("X2")).ToArray()));
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I will change that log line to something like this and see what happens.

Comment: I did that and you were right!  There was an [EOT] byte (4) in the beginning of the message and for some reason the logger did not print it into the log file.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the stack trace, it seems to be cycling through the matching files in the given directory, and then trying to obtain a full path using `Path.InternalCombine()`. That checks the for invalid characters, which throws the exception.

Since invalid characters in your `storePath` variable should have thrown an exception in the `DirectoryInfo` constructor, I see only one ways that an invalid character could creep in:

*One of the file names in the directory contains an illegal character.*

Sounds silly, but stranger things have happened... You can check if that is the cause by getting a file listing from that directory, preferably by running the `dir` command on the command line, and piping the result into a text file.

**Edit:**
Just saw that you already did - and it seems I was wrong. In that case I concur with [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9705448/22114), the only remaining suspect is the `deviceId`. See if you can log a hex representation of the string, as shown [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/236816-converting-integer-hex-string), that should also show `\0` and any other special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I was scanning a directory on a mac (through a network share).

> DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(@"//macbook/sharedfolder")

Apperenately it's quite legal on a mac to have chars like <,>,? in a filename, but on windows it's not.

When one of the filenames in the directory had invalid chars I got this "illegal characters" error.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception when I tried calling
`new DirectoryInfo(folderPath).GetFiles("x??\\*.dll")`

So as far as I can tell `GetFiles()` does not support using a wildcard for a directory name. So instead, I used this statement, which worked:
`new DirectoryInfo(folderPath).GetDirectories("x??").SelectMany(d => d.GetFiles("*.dll"))`

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get all the files that match a base file name then underscore and anything before the file extension. I get this same error when I do.

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txtAlternateImagesFolder.Text);
    string matchPattern = imageFileName.Replace(".jpg", "_*.jpg");
    var alternates = di.GetFiles(@matchPattern);
```

Then I tried this instead:

```
string matchPattern = imageFileName.Replace(".jpg", "");
var alternates = di.GetFiles(matchPattern).Where(f => f.Name.Contains(matchPattern) && f.Name!=imageFileName);
```

I didn't get an error, but neither did I pick up the matching files. I needed the wildcard "*" that was causing the exception. So my next attempt was:

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo($@"   {txtAlternateImagesFolder.Text}");
var images = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
//Skipping some use feedback code
        string matchPattern = imageFileName.Replace(".jpg", "*.jpg");
        var matches = images.Where(f => f.Name.Contains(matchPattern) && f.Name != imageFileName);
```

My theory was that if I used the wildcard normally in the GetFiles() method but not in the Where() predicate, it might not blow up. Nice theory, but no joy. I finally had to muscle it by defining the match with wildcards as "containing the filename without the extension, but not the same as the filename."

Answer (score -1):

You can not have a ? in a file name.  `\ / : * ? " < > |` are not valid characters for a file name.

EDIT:
CheckInvalidPathChars  is looking for the following characters:

num == 34 || num == 60 || num == 62 || num == 124 || num < 32

Why not implement this in your code as well and throw / handle your own exception.

Comment: Wrong: `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(string)` accepts ? and * wildcards

Comment: Yup, exactly - try this:  var files = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\").GetFiles("1234_????.txt"); - perfectly valid.